# C++ dynamic_cast access violation

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I'v read some of the similar titled questions and seem not much relevant.

I'm using Clang LibTooling, the following code in ASTVisitor:

```
virtual bool VisitCXXRecordDecl(CXXRecordDecl *d) {
    bool b1 = std::is_polymorphic<NamedDecl>::value;
    bool b2 = std::is_polymorphic<CXXRecordDecl>::value;
    auto dd = dynamic_cast <NamedDecl*>(d);
    auto ddd = dynamic_cast <CXXRecordDecl*>(dd);
    return true;
}
```

The second dynamic cast will trigger

```
"0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000004."
```

in VS2017.

The classes's relations are here http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXRecordDecl.html.

**Change to static_cast solve the problem**.

b1 and b2 are both true. dd is successfully casted, here is the "Locals" pane in VS2019 before executing the second dynamic cast:

```
+       d   ... clang::CXXRecordDecl *
+       dd  ... clang::NamedDecl * {clang::CXXRecordDecl}
```

In the route from NamedDecl to CXXRecordDecl, there is a multiple inheritence :

```
class TagDecl : public TypeDecl, public DeclContext, public Redeclarable<TagDecl>
```

I don't know whether this is relevant.

Comment: What is `CXXRecordDecl`? What is `NamedDecl`? How are they (if at all) related? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: You should check result of `dynamic_cast` or use `polymorphic_downcast` from boost (which throws exceptions on fail). This address `0x0000000000000004` suggests that you're essentially trying to dereference `nullptr` pointer.

Comment: @Some programmer dude These are open source Clang components, here is its relation graph: http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXRecordDecl.html

Comment: @Inline The result seems to be OK, the question mentioned that the first cast result is good. By "deference nullptr" did you mean dd is null (which is not)?

Answer (score 0):

You must turn on "Enable Run-Time Type Information (/GR)" in the project configuration to use `dynamic_cast`.